# Make an image appear on the canvas after x amount of seconds

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I want to draw an image on to the canvas after say 5 seconds. Once it has been drawn i want it to move down the screen a little and then just stop.

Is there any way to do this?

Here is the technique I've tried:

> I have the image moving down the canvas using a simple for loop and
>   maxY property of the image. However the image appears straight away
>   without a delay of 5 seconds.

Comment: yes. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes i have the image moving down the canvas using a simple for loop and maxY property of the image. However the image appears straight away without a delay of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the image is correctly loaded using `onload` you can do this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = ready;
img.src = "...";

function ready() {
    var maxY = 200, y = 0;
    setTimeout(animate, 5000);                            // delay animation

    function animate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, y);
        y++;
        if (y < maxY) requestionAnimatinFrame(animate);  // continue until criteria
    }
}
```

Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTimeout function, the second argument represents the delay you looking for in miliseconds

```
window.setTimeout(function() { //do you work here }, 5000);
```

Comment: ...and about the "moving" part of the question: Html canvas drawings cannot be moved or deleted--they are permanent as dried paint on a canvas. Instead you must clear the canvas and redraw any desired content in its "moved" position (or not redraw content to "delete" that content).